# Swift 2.2 for loop with decreasing iterator

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

Sometimes I need to use for loop that iterates from end of array. Since Swift 2.2 Xcode says that it is deprecated and I cannot find any way to write it now.

Example:

```
for var i = (tableData.count - 1); i >= 0; i-- {

}
```

I know that standard for loop can be rewritten like this:

```
for i in 0 ..< blocks.count {

}
```

Is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `reverse()` function

```
for i in (0 ..< tableData.count).reverse() { }
```